# How to make DDL Trigger for a specific table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a DDL trigger for a specific table and this is the best I could come up with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON DATABASE
FOR DDL_TABLE_EVENTS
AS
DECLARE @EventData      xml
SET @EventData=EVENTDATA()

IF @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(50)')='TABLE'
    AND @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ='MyTable'
BEGIN
    --do something special here!!
END
GO
```

**Is this really the only way to do it?**  I looked everywhere but couldn't find a syntax to create the trigger on a spceific table.  I think it is really silly needing to use the xml EVENTDATA().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's the way to do it. DDL triggers are associated with the database rather than individual objects. As a consequence, you can't subscribe directly to DDL events happening only on a specific object.

Answer (score 1):

DDL triggers such as `DDL_TABLE_EVENTS` (or such as `ALTER_TABLE` or `DROP_TABLE) fire for actions relating to object categories, rather than specific instances of an object.

Ref. [Designing DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)